# Free Microsoft Project file (.mpp) viewer

Tags: gratis, windows-7, project-management, desktop-client

I am looking for a Microsoft Project file (.mpp) viewer with the following characteristics:

- free for files of all sizes (this rules out [Project Viewer 365](http://www.projectviewercentral.com/projectviewer/projectviewerfree.html) which is only free for files up to 2 MB)
- runs on Windows 7 (this rules out Microsoft's [ProjectViewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/projectviewer/9wzdncrdfc3n) which only runs on Windows 8.1 and 10)
- runs as a desktop program and is not web-based

I have used [MPP Viewer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mppviewer/) 2.02, which worked on one of our old .mpp files.  However it crashes on our latest .mpp file.  I tried using the 3.0 Beta and it still crashes on the file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [Project Libre](http://www.projectlibre.org/).

This is an open source application that can view - and edit - files in Microsoft Project format.

It has versions for Windows, Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I'm content with [MS Project Viewer by Seavus](https://www.seavusprojectviewer.com/). The web application is free to use, open to all users, and provides accurate data representation.

Besides, it will open .mpp file of any MS Project version.

No installation needed, just head to the Online App and open your plan instantly.